What happens if I assign a Fortran character type using a literal that is too short?
Suppose I have the following Fortran code:
character(len=1000) :: my_string
my_string = "hello world!"

Since hello world! is only 12 characters long, what happens to the other 988 characters in my_string? Is this defined in the standard or is the behavior implementation-dependent?
